# Why when I enter the command "hostname" it returns something other than my computers name?

Tags: command-line, terminal, osx, hostname

*I am using a macBook Pro*
I enter: `new-host-2:~ Justin$ hostname`
And it returns: `new-host-2.home`

Why is this when it says in setting/sharing my computers name is "Justin's macbook pro" and computers on my local network can access my computer at "Justins-MacBook-Pro.local"

The tutorial I am reading says that the command should return one of the "many" names of your computer, I am assuming this is one, but if it is where else on my computer can I find this name or a list of names for my computer? And why did it not return "Justins-MacBook-Pro.local", this format was what the tutorials computer returned?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://superuser.com/q/357159/151431

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAC OS X maintains at least three different names for different usages (`ComputerName`, `HostName` and `LocalHostName`).

You can set the command line `hostname` to a different value with this command:

```
scutil --set HostName "justins"
```